# vue-material state change ui update messing with layout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions, vue-material

I have a login form with a submit button. As soon as you press the button a axios api request is sent. During this request the button should get disabled showing a spinner. Now, I managed to update the state accordingly using vuex. Now this looks like this:

[image]
What is happening here? The transition from `normal` -> `loading` state works just fine. But transitioning back from `loading` -> `normal` as soon as the api request is done messes up the layout for a second or so, before the rendering engine (not sure) resets the layout and re-centers the label.

this is my template for the button:

```
    <md-button @click.prevent="onBtnLoginClicked"
               class="md-raised md-primary"
               :disabled="isExecutingLogin">
      <span v-if="!isExecutingLogin">
        Login
      </span>
      <span v-else-if="isExecutingLogin">
        <md-progress-spinner id="spinner" :md-diameter="20" :md-stroke="3"
                             md-mode="indeterminate"/>
      </span>
    </md-button>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: check the `position` on the element with the CSS inspector and see if it changes

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there are both components visible for a short periode of time before the spinner-span disappears again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add `key` to the `span`s](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key). Issues like this do happen sometimes when switching between elements with the same name tag.

```html
<md-button @click.prevent="onBtnLoginClicked"
           class="md-raised md-primary"
           :disabled="isExecutingLogin">
  <span v-if="!isExecutingLogin" key="login">
    Login
  </span>
  <span v-else-if="isExecutingLogin" key="spinner">
    <md-progress-spinner id="spinner" :md-diameter="20" :md-stroke="3"
                         md-mode="indeterminate"/>
  </span>
</md-button>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jppmx3mrwy) -- The code is in `components/App.vue`. The spinner won't show, though (unrelated to your issue).

Answer (score 0):

Since `isExecutingLogin` is boolean, try a simple `<span v-else>`.

```html
<span v-if="!isExecutingLogin">
  Login
</span>
<span v-else>
  <md-progress-spinner id="spinner" :md-diameter="20" :md-stroke="3"
                       md-mode="indeterminate"/>
</span>
```

Logically, it should not make a difference but perhaps the second evaluation is briefly causing the two bits of content to be visible at once.